# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint"

Tags: c++, macos

For my ElectronJS project, I tried to create a native module using C++ which can move a mouse pointer on the screen. To move the cursor on MacOS I found CGEvent package but every time I try to build it using `make main` (based on some StackOverflow replies, I also tried `g++ main.cpp -o main`) it returns an error saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint", referenced from:
      _main in main-d4ae98.o
  "_CGMainDisplayID", referenced from:
      _main in main-d4ae98.o
```

`main.cpp` file:

```
#include <CoreGraphics/CGEvent.h>

int main() {
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    CGDirectDisplayID display = CGMainDisplayID();
    CGError move = CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(display, point);
}
```

Comment: `#include "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CGEvent.h"` - This isn't ok. You should NEVER use any kind of absolute path in an include. You need to specify the right frameworks in order for Clang to find them.

Comment: Also, on macOS `gcc` and `g++` are symlinks to `clang` and `clang++` respectively, unless you install GCC from Homebrew or MacPorts. They are there only to avoid older scripts from breaking, just invoke `clang++`.

Comment: I have changed the absolute path to <CoreGraphics/CGEvent.h> and tried running ```clang++``` but it still shows the same error...

Comment: Have you appended `-framework CoreGraphics` to your invocation to Clang? You must specify that you want to use a given macOS framework, or the compiler won't be able to find it.

Comment: Also, `main()` defines the entrypoint of a program, which I highly doubt is what you want given you wrote that you're trying to write an Electron module.

Comment: @mcilloni I've tried running ```clang++ main.cpp -framework CoreGraphics``` which produced a file called ```a.out``` (not sure how I could use it). But your comment guided me into adding ```CoreGraphics.framework``` as a framework in XCode which was able to build the file successfully without any errors (so if you wish, you can answer my question that way).

Comment: @mcilloni I know that the entry point of Electron's .cc files should be ```Initialize``` with a ```NODE_SET_METHOD``` set to export C++ function... The reason I used main as my entry point of the program is to compile it as a regular C++ file and see if my code produces any errors as it runs after building ```.node``` file.